# Why does my JQuery plugin work perfectly in Firefox but not in IE?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-7

I'm using JQuery 1.4.2, and trying to build a plugin that essentially shows a pick list from a table. I am using Jquery UI css classes for formatting the container that the pick list appears in, and [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) plugin for formatting the table, retrieving the data and filtering the table. The pick list works perfectly in FireFox 3.6 but in IE 7 the list never appears. I am not sure if this is due to positioning -- I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

```
(function($) {
  // Shell for the plugin code
  $.fn.tablePicker = function(options) {
    // Plugin code
    var tbl = null;
    var options= options = $.extend({},$.fn.tablePicker.defaults, options); 
    return this.each(function() {
      // for each item in selector
      tbl= $('#'+options.tblName);
      $(tbl).wrap(options.container);
      if(options.header != null){
          var headerHtml= '<div align="center">' + options.header + '</div>';
          $(this).find("#tp-container").prepend(headerHtml);
      }
      $(this).addClass("ui-hidden-on-load").addClass("ui-tablepicker");
      $(this).addClass("ui-widget").addClass("ui-widget-content");
      $(this).addClass("ui-helper-clearfix").addClass("ui-corner-all");
      $(this).addClass("ui-helper-hidden-accessible");
      $(this).css("position", options.position);
      var offsetFromObject= null;
      var offset= {top:null, left:null};
      try {
          if(options.forinput){
              offsetFromObject= options.forinput;
          }else if(options.forAnchor) {
              offsetFromObject= options.forAnchor;
          }else{
              alert("Warning: Tablepicker plugin did not find any control to bind to.");
          }
          // Use the specified parameter first
          if(options.top != null){
              offset.top= options.top;
          }else{
              var t= $("#"+offsetFromObject).offset();
              offset.top= t.top;
          }
          if(options.left != null){
              offset.left= options.left;
          }else{
              var l= $("#"+offsetFromObject).offset();
              offset.left= l.left;
          }
          $(this).offset(offset);
          $(this).css("z-index", "1");
      } catch (e) {
        alert('Tablepicker problem' + e);
      }
      tbl= _setUpDataTable(tbl);
      _performBindings(tbl, this);


    });
    function _setUpDataTable(tbl){
        tbl= $(tbl).dataTable( {
            "aoColumns"         : options.aoColumns,
            "bFilter"           : options.bFilter,
            "bPaginate"         : options.bPaginate,
            "bLengthChange"     : options.bLengthChange,
            "bAutoWidth"        : options.bAutoWidth,
            "sScrollY"          : options.sScrollY,
            "sPaginationType"   : options.sPaginationType,
            "bProcessing"       : options.bProcessing,
            "sAjaxSource"       : options.sAjaxSource
        });
        return tbl;
    };
    function _performBindings(dataTable, picker){
        var tableName= options.tblName;
        // Bind hide list to all inputs
        var tableFilter= tableName + '_filter';
        $('input, select').live('focus', function(event) {
            if ($(event.target).parent().attr('id') != tableFilter) {
                _hideList(picker); // Don't hide the list on the datatable filter input focus.
            }
        });
        // Don't bind hide list to the field we want to show the list for
        if(options.forinput != null){
            var inputToBind=$('#'+options.forinput);
            $(inputToBind).unbind('focus');
            // Bind to the field to show the list on.   
            $(inputToBind).focus(function() {
                if (!$(picker).is(':visible')) {
                    $(picker).slideToggle();
                }
            });
        }
        // Allow binding to an anchor
        if(options.forAnchor != null){
            $("#"+options.forAnchor).click(function() {
                if (!$(picker).is(':visible')) {
                    $(picker).slideToggle();
                }
            });
        }
        // Bindings for mouse over on table
        var tbl= $('#'+tableName); 
        $(tbl).find('tbody tr').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
            if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
                $(this).addClass('hover');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('hover');
            }
        });
        // handle the click event of the table
        $(tbl).find('tbody tr').live('click', function(event, ui) {
            var aData = dataTable.fnGetData(this);
            if (aData != null) {
                $.isFunction(options.onClick) && options.onClick.call(this, aData);
            }
            _hideList(picker);
            dataTable.fnFilter(""); // clear the datatable filter on select.
            $("#"+tableFilter).find("input").val("");

        });
        // Hide list on esc.
        $(document).keyup(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) { // esc
                    _hideList(picker);
                }
        });

    }
    function _hideList(picker) {
        if ($(picker).is(':visible')) {
            $(picker).slideToggle();
        }
    }

  }
  $.fn.tablePicker.defaults = {
    header      :   null,
    container   :   '<div id="tp-container" class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"/>',
    position    :   'absolute',
    top         :   null,
    left        :   null,
    tblName     :   'list_table',
    forinput    :   null,
    forAnchor   :   null,
    aoColumns   :   null,
    bFilter     :   true,
    bPaginate   :   true,
    bLengthChange : false,
    bAutoWidth  :   true,
    sScrollY    :   "200px",
    sPaginationType : "full_numbers",
    bProcessing :   true,
    sAjaxSource :   null,
    onClick     :   null

  };
})(jQuery);
```

I'm invoking the plugin as such:

```
$("#engine-picker").tablePicker(
       {forinput: "engineFamily",
          header: "Pick an Engine Family from this list. Use Search to narrow list.",
         onClick: function(data){
            var id = data[0];
            var family = data[1];
            var vendor = data[2];
            var year = data[3];
            var source = data[4];
            var usesOdometer= data[5];
            $("#engineId").val(id);
            $("#engineFamily").val(family);
            $("#engineMfg").val(vendor);
            $("#engineYear").val(year);
            $("#odometer").val(usesOdometer);
        },
        aoColumns: [ {"bVisible" : false}, null, null, null, null, {"bVisible" : false}],
        sAjaxSource: './enginelist-data.do',
        top: 296,
        left:602
});
```

CSS Classes:

```
.ui-hidden-on-load{display: none;}
.ui-tablepicker { width: 35em; padding: .25em .25em 0; z-index: 1}
.ui-tablepicker .ui-tablepicker-header { position:relative; padding:.2em 0; }
.ui-widget-header div{ width: 100%}
```

Thanks in advance for any/all replies!

---

OK, so the pick list table is not appearing on the page, because somehow the top attribute of the div is getting set to a negative value.

```
Z-INDEX: 1; LEFT: 404px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: -736px
```

Even though when I step through the code, I am explicitly setting the top and left via the offset object to:

```
-   offset  {...}   Object
    top 296 Long
    left    602 Long
```

Does anyone see what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in chaining the css position to the JQuery stack of commands that showed the table. For some reason this didn't seem to be a problem in FireFox, but did in IE7.

I changed my plugin to create a global variable for the offset.

```
(function($) {
  // Shell for the plugin code
  $.fn.tablePicker = function(options) {
    // Plugin code
    var tbl = null;
    var options= options = $.extend({},$.fn.tablePicker.defaults, options);
    var offset= {top:null, left:null};
return this.each(function() {
// for each item in selector
tbl= $('#'+options.tblName);
offset= $(this).offset(); ...
```

Then I replaced all of the places where I was showing the list with a method that passed a reference to the plugin as such:

```
function _showList(picker){
    var t= offset.top;
    var l= offset.left;
    $(picker).css("top", t+"px").css("left", l+"px").slideToggle();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am too lazy to set all that up so I can see it from here, but if I were debugging this, I would use the IE F12 tools to find the bits of the DOM which I can't see, and then work out why I couldn't see them.

I also think this:

```
<div id="tp-container" class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"/>
```

may be invalid - you can't have an empty div, and should have `<div blah-blah></div>`

In general, a lot of the browser differences I see turn out to be invalidities in something I'm doing, which one browser is more tolerant of than another.

e.g. Firefox will parse some kinds of invalid JSON which IE and Chrome won't.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was unaware of the developer tools add-in for IE7 & IE8, as I am always relying on firefox/firebug. This helped me find out why the div not showing up, now I need to find the cause. I'm explicitly setting the top:left attributes of $(this) -- in my plugin, but it seems the top attribute is getting set to a negative # despite the explicit call. $(this) must not be the correct context for IE?  (See amended post above)